# is Custom ios framework(Static framework) will run in another thread or in UI Thread?

Tags: ios, swift, nsthread, swift-custom-framework

i am very new to creating custom framework in ios.
I want to run custom framework in new custom thread, How can i do that?

Comment: Why do you want to run the framework in another thread?

Comment: @Michael : I am using async operation inside my framework. so i m trying like this

Comment: So the async operation runs in another thread, but not the call to your framework. Your framework function can use dispatch_async or NSOperation (for example) to run tasks in the background.